# C - return value at index: control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error

First of all: I just recently started programming in C (my first programming language) and this may be a stupid/simple question, but I was trying to implement a function which returns the value at index in an array/list. I always get this error from the compiler: "error: compiler reaches end of non-void function" even though I am returning values of type int. Thanks in advance:

```
int list_get(int list[], int length, int index) {
  if(index <= CAPACITY){
     for(int i = 0; i <= CAPACITY; i++){
        if(i == index)
            return list[i];
     }
  }
  else{
     printf("Index is out of range. \n");
     return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Need `return 0;` after for-loop.

Comment: Or without using a loop like  `if(0 <= index && index < length) return list[i] else { printf("Index is out of range. \n");
     return 0; }`

Comment: `list[i]` of previous my comment typo as `list[index]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler sees, both the `return` statements are under some sort of *conditional* block, so it tries to warn you. Nothing wrong, as such.

Consider the flow,

- `index <= CAPACITY` is true,
- for none of the iterations, `i == index` is true.
- for loop is exited.

In that case, there's nothing to be returned....

To avoid, just move the `return 0;` statement out of `else` block. be aware of the possible side effect, if `i == index` check fails, it will return 0.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function does not make sense. The parameter `length` is not used within the function. Also there is no need to include a loop that to check that index is less than or equal to the magic value `CAPACITY`.

The compiler issues a message because it is unable to determine that this condition

```
if(i == index)
```

will be always true provided that this condition

```
if(index <= CAPACITY){
```

is also true.

Also it is not clear how to distinguish 0 from a valid value in the array at the index.

Answer (score 0):

your else statement is out of for loop.so when your for loop exits it execute statement of else and there you have written "return 0". so it won't return any value.